# git log: what is the placeholder for tag names

Tags: git

I want to save the `git log` output to a file with a specific format, including tag names.

```
git --no-pager log --oneline --format="%h, %ad, %cn, %s, <tag>" --date=format:"%Y-%m" > gitlog.txt
```

What is the placeholder for the tag name ?

Comment: You can see supported placeholders [in the docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats); tags are part of the ref name list (e.g. in my current repo `git log -n1 --pretty=format:'%d'` -> _" (HEAD -> main, **tag: v9.0.0**, origin/main, origin/HEAD)"_).